# Introspection in C# on java library in unity

Tags: java, c#, ikvm

I've used IKVM to convert a java library into a .dll to use in my unity application.

How do i write this java line in c#:

```
ProjectController pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController.class);


org.gephi.project.api.ProjectController pc = org.openide.util.Lookup.getDefault().lookup(org.gephi.project.api.ProjectController.class);
```

Introspection doesn't seem to work. There seems to be a problem when i refer to  ProjectController.class

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of a Java class at runtime in .NET is a System.Type object. There are two ways to get one: call `GetType()` on any object instance (comes from System.Object, so everything supports it) or use [the `typeof` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx).

You *might* also just be able to use the raw class name, but I would expect it to want the Type object. It will depend on how IKVM implements Java reflection; I really don't know.

Of course, you could possibly also just do the whole thing using .NET reflection. I don't *know* if that's equivalent to what your example lines do, because you're using some strange non-standard Java-reflection-like thing, but it looks like you're just trying to get the "default" instance of a class...?

```
// I haven't tested this, but it may work:
ProjectController pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(typeof(ProjectController));
// You could also just try it without the ".class" part (since "class" is reserved in C#):
ProjectController pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController);
// Or, if you want the .NET reflection "proper" way to do what I *think* you're attempting:
ProjectController pc = typeof(ProjectController).GetContructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);
// Of course, that's just the same thing as this simple line, so I probably misunderstood:
ProjectController pc = new ProjectController();
```